# How to export/generate a RGB/stack raster based on raster visualization palette in R

Tags: raster, r, rgb

I have this data:

```
r <-raster(volcano)
```

And the plot generated:

```
plot(r)
```

[image]

How to generate or export a raster with this color palette (or any other) with spatial reference?A RGB/stack raster. For instance, in QGIS we can export a raster as a rendered image after defined the renderization.

[image]

Comment: Do you want the axes and legend included? Or just the raster itself?

Comment: Just the raster itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `palr` package has a function `image_raster` for the task of *baking in the palette* to RGB version of the raster. (You can set the extent and projection using raster itself as usual).

```r
library(raster)
#> Loading required package: sp
r <-raster(volcano)

library(palr)

## apply the colours used by raster plot() itself
rgb0 <- image_raster(r, col = rev(terrain.colors(255)))
plotRGB(rgb0)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

There are arguments to control the `col`, `breaks`, and `zlim` after `graphics::image()`.

Use `raster::writeRaster()` to create a GeoTIFF (or other format).

(To create PNG or JPEG I would convert the raster to array and use `png` or `jpeg` packages, just fwiw)

Comment: Good alternative this package.

Comment: One question. If I want to put contours like `contour(volcano)` is there any work around?

Comment: it's surprisingly hard to do that actually, you need to set up the *device* itself to be the same resolution as the data, then *draw to that*, add the contours, and then capture it to file (the device might be a file, but only png or tiff). So then you have to add the georef. It's on my list to "make easy", "illustrate" etc - one of those *obvious things* that the tools work against you unfort (I'll have a think about the easiest way)

Comment: I catch the basic idea. Who knows a possible update to this package ou an ideia to a new package transform any raster device to RGB

Comment: I just discover that `RGB()` function from raster package makes the same that `image_raster()`

Comment: huh, I didn't notice that - image_raster() is more compatible with image(), at least